# How to simulate 'friend' in C++ with int main()

Tags: c++, singleton, friend

I want to make a singleton class with no public methods. I have achieved this functionality with another class that is a `friend` of my `Main` (it has private methods access). But I want to make sure of the same functionality but in my `main` function. For example, I want to be able to include my `main.h` in many files, but deny them access to the `Mainloop()` method, rather just allow it to only be called in my `main.cpp` with the `int main()`.

Here is my **main.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

#include "events.h"



class Main    ///Singleton
{
public:
    Main(const Main&) = delete;
    Main(Main&&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(const Main&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(Main&&) = delete;


    static void Mainloop(); ///THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO BE PRIVATE BUT STILL CALLABLE



private:
    Main();


    static Main& Get_Instance();


    static void Init();
    static void Free();


    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    bool running = false;
    char mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'I';


};



#endif // MAIN_H
```

and **main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"





Main::Main()
{
    std::cout << "Main constructor called\n";
    mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'C';
}




Main& Main::Get_Instance()
{
    static Main instance;
    return instance;
}




void Main::Init()
{
    std::cout << "Main Init called\n";
    Get_Instance(); ///To initialize constructor in case it hasn't been


    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    TTF_Init();
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG);


    Get_Instance().window = SDL_CreateWindow("Program", 0, 30, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
    Get_Instance().renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Get_Instance().window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED  );

    Get_Instance().running = true;


    SDL_StartTextInput();
}



void Main::Free()
{

    SDL_StopTextInput();

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(Get_Instance().renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(Get_Instance().window);


    IMG_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    std::cout << "Main Free called\n";

}



void Main::Mainloop()
{

    Get_Instance(); ///To initialize constructor

    if (Get_Instance().mainloopInstanceBlocker == 'C')
    {
        Get_Instance().mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'B';   ///Begins at I (initialized), then C (constructed) then B (began)
                                        ///It works as it begins as constructed, then does the main loop, after set to B, won't enter again.

        Get_Instance().Init();
        Events::Get_Instance(); ///Initialize Events constructor



        while (Get_Instance().running)
        {
            ///Begin event handling
            Events::Event_Loop();
            if (Events::Quit_Application())
            {
                Get_Instance().running = false;
                break;
            }



            ///Clear display to color
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Get_Instance().renderer, 0,255,0,255);
            SDL_RenderClear(Get_Instance().renderer);




            ///Non negotiable end loop functions
            Events::Reset_Events();
            SDL_RenderPresent(Get_Instance().renderer);
            //SDL_Delay(1000/60);
        }




        Get_Instance().Free();


    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Called Main::Mainloop(); more than once\n";
    }

}





int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Main::Mainloop();

    return 0;
}
```

**events.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef EVENTS_H
#define EVENTS_H


#include "main.h"



class Events    ///Singleton
{
public:
    Events(const Events&) = delete;
    Events(Events&&) = delete;
    Events& operator=(const Events&) = delete;
    Events& operator=(Events&&) = delete;



    ///Mouse
    static const SDL_Point& Mouse_Pos();


    ///Keyboard
    static const std::string& User_Text_Input();

    static const bool& User_Backspace();



private:
    Events();


    static Events& Get_Instance();


    ///Allow Main to access private members. Works well, one instance, only called once for those functions too. in Main
    friend class Main;

    ///For event handling
    static void Event_Loop();


    ///For event handling
    static void Reset_Events();


    ///For quitting, used main only
    static const bool& Quit_Application();



    ///For Event_Loop()
    int eventLoopCounter = 0;   ///To ensure Event_Loop() doesn't get used twice in the same loop
    SDL_Event event;




    bool m_quit = false;

    ///Mouse
    SDL_Point m_Mouse_Pos = {0,0};

    ///Keyboard
    std::string m_User_Text_Input = "";
    bool m_User_Backspace = false;



};



#endif // EVENTS_H
```

and **events.cpp**

```
#include "events.h"


Events::Events()
{
    std::cout << "Events constructor called\n";
}


Events &Events::Get_Instance()
{
    static Events instance;
    return instance;
}




void Events::Event_Loop()
{
    Get_Instance();

    if (Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter == 0)
    {

        Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter += 1;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&Get_Instance().event) != 0)
        {
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                Get_Instance().m_quit = true;
                break;
            }

            ///Mouse
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            {
                Get_Instance().m_Mouse_Pos = {Get_Instance().event.motion.x, Get_Instance().event.motion.y};
            }




            ///Keyboard
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
            {
                Get_Instance().m_User_Text_Input = Get_Instance().event.text.text;
                //break;  ///Break here for multiple key presses registered at once
            }
            ///Keydown
            if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                if (Get_Instance().event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_BACKSPACE)
                {
                    Get_Instance().m_User_Backspace = true;
                }
            }


        }

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Called Events::Event_Loop(); more than once\n";
    }

}



void Events::Reset_Events()
{
    Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter = 0;

    Get_Instance().m_quit = false;

    ///Mouse


    ///Keyboard
    Get_Instance().m_User_Text_Input = "";

    Get_Instance().m_User_Backspace = false;


}


const bool& Events::Quit_Application()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_quit;
}


///Mouse
const SDL_Point& Events::Mouse_Pos()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_Mouse_Pos;
}



///Keyboard
const std::string& Events::User_Text_Input()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_User_Text_Input;
}


const bool& Events::User_Backspace()
{
    return Get_Instance().m_User_Backspace;
}
```

Comment: If only `main.cpp` should know about `Mainloop()`, why not just declare the function there?

Comment: It needs to access the member variables. Im not sure if I can but I want to make my other classes inherit from my ```Main``` so they have access to the ```window``` and ```renderer``` but not call its constructor

Comment: So, the derived classes will also have a `MainLoop` each? I think you need to show more details about how this is going to fit together. Why should they inherit from `Main` when they are not a type of `Main`?

Comment: fair point. I guess what im more interested in is inheriting just the ```window``` and ```renderer```, but even then, how can I make sure ```MainLoop``` is private for where I ```#include "main.h"``` other files can't access it

Comment: Make a [mre] with the classes and comment on the functions you'd like to protect.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I re-edited the question. As is my current bandaid solution, I made a variable that doesn't ```stop``` it from being called, rather stops the execution of any of its functionality. I don't necessarily want this though as its redundant compared to if the method was entirely not able to be called

Comment: Why not just make main a friend of Main?

Comment: How can I do that? I'm pretty sure ```friend``` needs to be used inside of a class @Yakk-AdamNevraumont

Comment: Yes?  Inside `class Main` make `friend int main(blah blah)`.

Comment: Oh wow ahaha what that worked?? Thanks thats brilliant! @Yakk-AdamNevraumont

Comment: There is nothing in your example code that shows why `events.h` needs to `#include "main.h"`. In fact, you currently have a circular inclusion, which is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @JaMiT ```events.h``` needs to include ```main.h``` because I need it to allow ```Main``` to be a ```friend``` class of ```Events```. I have ```#ifndef``` guards and ```#pragma once``` so it should be fine?

Comment: @asdfgodsia123e890dik No it does not need to be included. See [friend declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend). You are using form 3. *"The name of the class that is used in this friend declaration does not need to be previously declared."*